# Wamp redirecting to wrong path

Tags: php, apache, drupal, wampserver

When i am clicking on the link to another page from my welcome page to a page in drupal site like

```
localhost/mysite/welcome
```

It should go to

```
localhost/mysite/myprofile
```

But instead its going to

```
localhost/myprofile
```

The rewrite module is enabled in the wamp . I looked into .htaccess file also but could not make out what's happening ? Any Ideas

Comment: Have you configured the alias in your apache conf ? Could you paste your apache configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the handbook if you haven't already, the section "Subdirectory multi-site" could help you on this page : https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site.